# "connecting" files in unix

Tags: files

I was wondering if there is a way in unix (like) environments to connect groups of files and easily view those groups and select specific files from the group.

Of course one way would be to put files in each group in its own directory but I am thinking about the following situation. I could have a directory of pdf papers. I write notes on individual papers and would like to connect or associate note1 and note7 with paper1, note 1 and note 3 with paper 2 and so on. Or at the same time I would like to associate paper 3 and paper 8 with note 2. With that association I would then like to be able to (for example) "select" paper1 and have note1 and note 7 identified as being connected and allow me to select one of them to view/edit OR I would like to be able to "select" note 2 and then the list containing paper3 and paper 8 would be identified from which I could choose to view/edit either file.

I would like to have a terminal/command-line solution. Suggestions?

Comment: You have 2 entities (notes papers) and 1 relationship (many-to-many). Use sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion in general terms: store every file in a `./__RAW__` folder, and have a `./connections` text file having all “connections”; this can be a simple “every line has all inter-connected filenames” or “every line describes dependent: dependencies” (a graph).

Then you can have a script create a subdirectory structure based on the `./connections` file.